# How Do I Increase the Search Text in my Navigation

Tags: search, bigcommerce

I am using Bigcommerce and their them Corner Stone.

How do I increase the size of the "SEARCH" text font?

I attached a screen shot image with a blue circle showing where the "search" text is.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0U1t.png)

Thank you

Comment: Go to your admin->storefront->Advanced -> theme editor, then go to assets-> scss -> theme.scss
add below css and you're done...
body li.navUser-item .navUser-action--quickSearch {
    font-size: 22px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your theme, you may be able to make this change by navigating to Storefront > My Theme in your back office.

However, it's likely that the font size for that one component is the same for the rest of them; in that case, you may have to make manual changes to the CSS stylesheets by editing your theme files.